# CORS does not work in ASP.NET-Core-Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, odata

I want to add a policy to my web-odataAPi-application to only allow communication from one address.

In my understanding something like this in the Startup:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "AllowSpecificOrigins",
                    co => co
                                    .WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000/")
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .WithMethods()
                                    .AllowCredentials());

                options.DefaultPolicyName = "AllowSpecificOrigins";
            });
```

In the configure:

```
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins");
```

Above a Get-Route I do the followng:

```
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigins")]
```

When i run this request from the `https://localhost:5000` via Postman, Firefox and Chrome it works fine, even if in my understanding, it only should work form localhost:3000, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser security prevents a web page from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the web page. This restriction is called the same-origin policy. The same-origin policy prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site. Sometimes, you might want to allow other sites to make cross-origin requests to your app. For more information, see the Mozilla CORS [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

CORS is not a security feature, CORS relaxes security. An **API** is not safer by allowing CORS. For more information, see [How CORS works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#how-cors).

Comment: So if i leave CORS out of my application i wont run into trouble? All in all, shouldnt i see anything in the header, like: ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ``` It boggles me that i dont see any result or behavior.

Comment: "So if i leave CORS out of my application i wont run into trouble?" not exactly. It does prevent access to your API when another website tries to access your API data e.g via AJAX, the browser will not allow access to your API due to CORS. But if anyone tries to access your API via any other means like postman, Python script he will not any CORS error.

Comment: Okay thank you for making this clear to me - do you have any idea, why there is no sign of behavior in the response or anywhere else?

Comment: Please [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#how-cors).

Comment: Thank you, sorry i should`ve read it in more detail. So there is no behavior because the cross-origin request fails, right?

Comment: What do you mean by behavior?

Comment: It does not matter if I implement the ```AddCors()``` or ```UseCors()``` into the StartUp. Even with ```AllowAny``` or ```WithOrigin("specificOrigin")``` there are no changes or any restrictions in the request or the response. I thought that if i leave it out i will get an error or if i allow anything i will at least get the ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin:```-Header

Comment: I finally understood why and how i was wrong and how CORS functions. The article that made it all clear to me was this one [link](http://performantcode.com/web/do-you-really-know-cors)